# List view item layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have this layout which is a row item of a ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:gravity="center" >

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/taskActiveToggleButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskScheduleTextView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/taskMenuButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="..." /></LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I am having troubles adding another button to left of the (...) button.

I want to add the button so the row will keep its proportions (take all width of the line)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the whole xml code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are using horizontal `LinearLayout` as a root layout for your items. I would change it to `RelativeLayout`. Also if you need your layout occupy the whole width - you need to get rid of `200dip` hardcoding and replace it with `match_parent`

Here is what I got using `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/taskActiveToggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/taskActiveToggleButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/anotherButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/taskNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/taskScheduleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sub Text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/anotherButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/taskMenuButton"
        android:text="But2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/taskMenuButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]